# How to use a type constraint with abstract type

Tags: scala, types

Given the following code :

```
trait S { type T }
case class A(t: Seq[String]) extends S { type T = Seq[String] }
```

I don't understand this compilation error :
It seems that the evidence is not used.

```
def f[S<:A, X](g: => Seq[X])(implicit ev: S#T =:= Seq[X]) = new A(g)

<console>:50: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[X]
 required: Seq[String]
       def f[S<:A, X](g: => Seq[X])(implicit ev: S#T =:= Seq[X]) = new A(g)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For how silly it may look, swapping the order of `=:=` operands solves the issue

```
def f[S<:A, X](g: => Seq[X])(implicit ev: Seq[X] =:= S#T) = new A(g)
```

Thank you, scalac.

#### explanation

When you say `implicit ev S#T =:= Seq[X]`, the compiler provides an implicit conversion from `S#T` to `Seq[X]`. It doesn't however provide an equivalent conversion from `Seq[X]` to `S#T`, and that's the silly part: isn't equality supposed to be commutative?

Some extra details on the subject here: http://typelevel.org/blog/2014/07/02/type_equality_to_leibniz.html

Comment: I don't see this in terms of equality, I see this in terms of conversions and there may be a type `A` which has a conversion method to `B` and not viceversa, commutativity in conversions is in general not guaranteed.

Comment: I see the =:= operator as equality operator. Not seeing this in terms of equality seems like a stretch